# webdriverIO 5, how to switch to iframe when its element 'id' not given?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, webdriver-io

```
frame html code:
<iframe title="frame report" class="ReportViewer__iframe" src="/yesyyy.aspx?reportId=145&amp;ts=1550681978158&amp;bgcolor=#f8f9fb" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>
```

script fails both for title and class name locators -- 'ERROR webdriver: Request failed due to Error: no such frame'

Comment: Update the question with your code trials

Comment: This is first iframe in the html, and id tag is not gievn. Using title xpath and .ReportViewer__iframe locator this comes:
 ERROR webdriver: Request failed due to Error: no such frame'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following code.

```
        driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
        WebElement frameXpath = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[@title='frame report']"));
        driver.switchTo().frame(frameXpath);
```

Comment: thanks for answering, 
but this is not the expected solution, I wanted to the take the context to iframe (first in the code), switching is failing in both xpath - title or class .ReportViewer__iframe selectors.

Comment: context will be switched to iframe when you use    driver.switchTo().frame(frameXpath); command. This xpath worked for me with mentioned iframe.

Comment: WebDriverIO have driver keyword?

Answer (score 1):

Got the solution, pass the object of the iframe with available locators (title or css class)
browser.switchtoframe($('.report__iframe'))

Comment: how you are verify does context switch to right iframe ?

Answer (score -1):

**HTML Code:**

> iframe id="ifr" name="demo" src="demo.html" height="200" width="300">

**Switch statement:**

> browser.switchToFrame($("//iframe[@src='demo.html']"))

**For more info read here:** https://chercher.tech/webdriverio/iframes