# Webdriver.IO[7] : SwitchToFrame with css selector is not working

Tags: javascript, ui-automation, webdriver-io, javascript-automation, wdio

I want to click web element inside the iframe and trying to switch to respective iframe before clicking to web element.
`browser.switchToFrame(number)` - switch to iframe with number is working but unable switch to iframe with css selector.

I have tried below code.

```
 await $('.framed_view').waitForDisplayed({ timeout: 5000 });
 const iframe = $('.framed_view');
 await browser.switchToFrame(iframe);
```

Comment: you are missing a await when getting the element from the DOM: "const iframe = await ${'.framed_view')

Answer (score 0):

Because it only accepts ID of the element. This method doesn't work the same way as usual $ calls.

See: [webdriver.io/docs/api/jsonwp/#switchtoframe](https://webdriver.io/docs/api/jsonwp/#switchtoframe)

Tbh, I had issues with switching to frames via this or similar wdio methods myself and never managed to get it working.

Comment: I was checking  few solution on stack overflow and blogs but hard luck for me. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65864821/how-to-handle-iframe-content-using-webdriverio-js-and-mocha                                                                                                         https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54799479/webdriverio-5-how-to-switch-to-iframe-when-its-element-id-not-given                                                                                               https://chercher.tech/webdriverio/iframes#handle-frames-webdriverio

Answer (score 0):

You can also use xpath to select Iframe.
This worked for me

```
get mainFrame() {
    return $("//devsite-iframe/iframe");
}
async switchFrame () {
    await this.mainFrame.waitForExist({ timeout: 3000 });
    await browser.switchToFrame(await this.mainFrame); 
}
```